# Incompatible Types android.view

Tags: java, android, view, types, return

My code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {   

...


// Page 1
    View android[]  = new View[3];
    android[0] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
    ((TextView) android[0].findViewById(R.id.textViewJuli01)).setText("Page1");


// page 2
     android[1] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
     ((TextView) android[1].findViewById(R.id.textViewJuli01)).setText("Page2");


     return android;
}
```

The error is shown at the last line "return android"

I got this message when I want to return an array.
I do not know how to solve this.
Has anyone a tip.

```
Incompatible Types
Required: android view.View
Found: android view.View[]
```

Comment: Show your java code/function that gives this error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the return type as "View", but you are returning android, which is "View[]" (array of View objects).  Android wants a single View to display.  I can think of a couple possible solutions:  If you intend to display only one of the pages (at least for now), then return that view and ignore the others.  IF you want the "pages" sharing the screen, then you can either combine them into one View, or create a Fragment for each "page", and then create a single View containing the fragments.